# While installing wiston on windows got the following error

Tags: node.js, logging

While installing wiston logger for node js, got the following error.

Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ndencies":{"assume":"'

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm install@latest -g
npm install winston

Comment: thanks for the answar.. but I found the alternative